# How to force another control to validate when a drop down's choice changes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a WPF application with a dialog that is displayed to edit some settings.  The dialog contains, among other things, a `ComboBox` and a `TextBox`.  The `ComboBox` has two choices in it.  The contents of the `TextBox` need to be validated when one of those two choices is selected and should not be validated when it isn't.  Here's the XAML for the two controls:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource LPRTypes}, Path=DisplayNames}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LPRTypes}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=LPRType}"
          Margin="5"
          Name="LPRTypePicker"
          TabIndex="1" />

<TextBox Margin="5,0,30,0"
         Name="DeviceIdBox"
         TabIndex="2"
         Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Path=DeviceId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         TextChanged="DeviceIdBox_TextChanged" />
```

I'm also using the following template to display validation errors to the user:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="InputErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Height="20"
                        Margin="-30,0,0,0"
                        Source="{StaticResource ErrorImage}"
                        ToolTip="{x:Static res:Car.Common_InvalidData}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="20" />
                <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                        BorderThickness="5"
                        Margin="5,0,30,0">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InputErrorTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent"
                                     RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I have the following code in the `IDataError` implementation in the `ViewModel` object for the dialog:

```
public string this[ string columnName ] {
    get {
        switch ( columnName ) {
            // . . .

            case "DeviceId":
                if ( LPRType == LPRTypes.AD3 )
                    return string.Empty;

                if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( DeviceId ) )
                    return Car.LPRCamera_MissingDeviceId;
                break;

                // . . .

            default:
                // Verify that the property name matches a real,  public, instance property on this object. 
                if ( TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( this )[ columnName ] == null ) {
                    return Car.ViewModelBase_InvalidProperty + columnName;
                }
                break;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The two possible values for `LPRType` are `Type1` and `Type2`.  When `LPRType` is `Type1`, the `DeviceId` column's value doesn't matter -- there should not be any error, even if it's null or empty.  But, if `LPRType` is `Type2`, then `DeviceId` must have a non-null or empty value.

If you set the `LPRType` to `Type2`, then delete all content in the `TextBox`, an error is displayed on the `TextBox`, which is correct.  Now, if you change the value of `LPRType` back to `Type1`, the UI still displays the `TextBox` as an error.  This is wrong, since the value of the `DeviceId` doesn't matter when `LPRType` is `Type1`.

How do I get the View Model to validate the `DeviceId` property when the `LPRType` changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work.  <del>I added a `SelectionChanged` event handler to the `ComboBox` and I put in code that sets the `DeviceId` property to its current value.</del>

I added a call to `OnPropertyChanged("DeviceId")` in the setter for the `LPRType` property.  In this way, the window thinks the `DeviceId` has changed and needs to be validated whenever the user changes the value of the `LPRType` property.

Thanks to Shoe for sparking the idea.  I'm giving him a plus 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can call INPC when IDataErrorInfo is called on one property which will rerun your validation for another property.

for example...

```
case "DeviceId":
    //IDataErrorInfo will run again with "MyOtherProperty" as the property upon calling
    OnPropertyChanged("MyOtherProperty");
    break;
case "MyOtherProperty":
    break;
```

Also, if possible you should look into `INotifyDataErroInfo` which is the .NET 4.5 replacement for `IDataErrorInfo`

Comment: You gave me an idea.  Another way to do it is to call OnPropertyChanged for the dependent property in the setter for the one it depends on. This works as well and is how my code now works.